# How to handle SignalR client exception in server (.Net)?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, signalr, signalr-hub

On the client, i did the following

```
        private async Task LogCallBack(Exception text)
        {
            try
            {
                await Send("ClientLogs", text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Serilog.Log.Error($"Exeption - {ex}");
            }
        }
```

In server side

```
        public void ClientLogs(Exception text)
        {
            Serilog.Log.Error(text);            
        }
```

And the text of this exception in server i get -
Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

How to get message for exception, stack trac, etc?